# как сравнить числа в файлах bash

Tags: linux, bash

Задача:
Найти файл в котором содержится самая большая цифра и самая маленькая из всех 100 файлов с указанием имени файла и самой цифры

Вот мой код:

```
max=0
min=0
for i in /home/dir/2021-11-25/File*
do
echo "$i"  #выводит список файлов в директории 2021-11-25
done
```

Не пойму как зайти в каждый файл и сравнить содержимое с остальными файлами.

P.S. На данный момент мой скрипт выводит только список файлов которые находятся в директории 2021-11-25, вот что сейчас выводит:

```
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File1
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File10
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File2
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File3
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File4
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File5
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File6
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File7
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File8
/home/dir/2021-11-25/File9
```

Comment: вопрос содержит много вопросов. Сократи до одного. Например, как открыть файл. Или как прочитать содержимое файла. И т.д. Не забудь самостоятельно поискать нужную информацию по все действиям, потому что они все элементарные и доступно примено 111555 примеров по каждому из них.

Comment: думаю в этой задаче смогут помочь программы `tail`, `cat` и `sort`, попробуйте прочитать их мануал и надеюсь решение найдется.

Comment: как зайти по очереди в каждый файл и сравнить его содержимое с остальными файлами

Comment: в условии задачи сказано найти файл, который содержит самую **большую** цифру. Вообще то цифры порядка не имеют, но для большинства это будет 9. грепаем файлы по наличию цифры 9. Если нашли - вот они файлы (или файл). Если нет - делаем тоже для 8 и так до 0.